# mac os x 10.7.5 virtualenv can't find easy_install

Tags: macos, virtualenv, python-3.3

Python 2.7.3 is default version on my mac os x. I have installed version 3.3.2 
When i create the virtual environment without specifying any version of python everything is fine

When i try to create a virtual environment using 3.3.2 ( with -p flag ), i am getting the following error:

```
Buraks-MacBook-Pro:VIRTUAL_ENVIRONMENTS burakk$ virtualenv -p /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3.3 django_ozo
Running virtualenv with interpreter /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3.3
New python executable in django_ozo/bin/python3.3
Also creating executable in django_ozo/bin/python
Installing distribute.................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................done.
Installing pip...
  Error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/burakk/BurakWorks/Web/VIRTUAL_ENVIRONMENTS/django_ozo/bin/easy_install' while executing command /Users/burakk/BurakW...ozo/bin/easy_install /Library/Python/2.7/...pport/pip-1.1.tar.gz
...Installing pip...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2270, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 928, in main
    never_download=options.never_download)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1042, in create_environment
    install_pip(py_executable, search_dirs=search_dirs, never_download=never_download)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 640, in install_pip
    filter_stdout=_filter_setup)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 966, in call_subprocess
    cwd=cwd, env=env)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/subprocess.py", line 820, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/subprocess.py", line 1438, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/burakk/BurakWorks/Web/VIRTUAL_ENVIRONMENTS/django_ozo/bin/easy_install'
```

Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

My virtualenv version was 1.7... Upgrading virtualenv to 1.10 solved the issue.